# How to call fetches sequentially (A -> B -> C) inside a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function-call

I have 3 fetch functions: `a()`, `b(a_id)`, `c(b_id)`. Function a will return an `a_id` and pass to function b, and b will return an `id` and pass to c.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  this.gotoanotherPage(this.props.a_id);
}

generateBody() {
  this.props.a();
  this.props.b(this.props.a_id);
  this.props.c(this.props.b_id);
}

render() {
  body = generateBody();
  return <framework {body}/>
}
```

My problem is `a()` has not finished fetching and getting a response back yet, yet `b` and `c` already execute and `this.props.a_id` and `this.props.b_id` are undefined. I couldn't modify the a,b, and c functions.

Anyone know how to set a function call in an order?

Comment: Do the functions a, b, and c return a promise?

Comment: please could you supply more details, thx

Comment: What does this.props.a return?  as well as the other functions?  Is it a void function, or does it return a value?  And if it returns a value what type of value does it return?

Comment: Function-a is a fetch call and it will return a string in Jason, then it will pass to function-b, function-b is a fetch call also, then it will return a string in Json too, then pass to function-c, function-c is a fetch call also. Function-c will return a Json string

Answer (score 1):

You can use `componentDidMount` to call the first fetch, then use `componentDidUpdate` to call the second fetch that depends on the first one. Then do the same thing for the third fetch.

You can use `prevProps` to check if you received the first and second responses.

Your component will look to something like this:

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchA();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!prevProps.a_id && this.props.a_id) { // it means you received a_id
      this.props.fetchB(this.props.a_id);
    }

    if (!prevProps.b_id && this.props.b_id) { // it means you received b_id
      this.props.fetchC(this.props.b_id);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <framework />
  }
}
```

Comment: I could not do it in this way, in the componenetDidUpdate, I also set to go to another page, so it will execute go to another page before get FetchB back. I need the response from function_b and function_c to output another page.

Comment: Like in my example, you can check if you received B and C before going to the other page.

Comment: it doesn't work in this way, at least it doesn't work in my case

Comment: I am thinking about using promise like var promise = new Promise(()=>this.props.a()); promise.then(this.props.a_id => this.props.b(a_id)); but it still execute b before a